# How to have 3 div side by side? No container?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to style 3 divs equally on the screen.  Each should have the same styling, as I'm trying to build a reusable block.

```
<div class="w-1/3 float-left flex flex-row></div>
<div class="w-1/3 float-left flex flex-row></div>
<div class="w-1/3 float-left flex flex-row></div>
```

The only solution that comes close is having

```
float: left;
```

But it's not filling the container in the back? Result is that the cards are above the page everything.

Comment: What do you mean by  container in the back? Can you show picture of the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the [inline block](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display#inline-block) solution as in the example below:

```
<div class="bg-blue-100 h-10">
<div class="bg-yellow-600 w-3/12 h-10  inline-block "></div>
<div class="bg-green-600 w-3/12 h-10  inline-block "></div>
<div class="bg-purple-600 w-3/12  h-10  inline-block "></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to put them all in the same row?

Answer (score -1):

For same style you can create style on style.css

and solution for same width i like to create like this;

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-1 ..."></div>
</div>
```